# How do I only load an image when the user scrolls to it

Tags: jquery, performance, image, scroll, lazy-loading

Many sites appear to only download images or generate parts of the document (eg for reviews) when the user scrolls far enough down the page to actually see them.

This obviously will give you faster loading pages and save on bandwidth for anyone that does not bother scrolling down.

How is this done, ideally with jquery? Or to ask it another way, how do I detect that a missing image has just scrolled into view and needs to be fetched?

Comment: Although I can understand the reasons behind developers wanting to do this, I do find it highly annoying having to wait for parts of the page to load. Plus if you scroll to the bottom of the page right away, as content loads the page jumps, so be sure to set your elements to blocks so the content doesn't jump about and make me cry ;)

Comment: This jumping thing is easily fixed by setting the height and width of the image in HTML, eg <img height='100' width='100' />. It's best practice, too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plugins for that. [Here's one](http://www.appelsiini.net/2007/9/lazy-load-images-jquery-plugin)...

Comment: from the author: `Lazy Load is currently not usable. It does not work with the latest browsers as expected. I have currently no time updating the code myself...`

Answer (score 6):

Here is my own. Have Fun. (doesn't require jQuery!)

**Tested:** IE 5.5+, FF 2+, Chrome, Opera 9.6+

**Usage:**

1. your lazyloaded images should have their real src in a thumb attribute
2. Just include the javascript file inline or externally.
3. If you don't want to use it on your entire page, you can do:

   ```
    LazyImg().destroy(); // stop global fetching
    LazyImg("watch-only-this-div");
   ```

   Note: when you include the file a global instance is already created watchin the whole document. You need to stop that first and start you own instance.

   4. set a custom offset for prefetching (how far below the fold the image should be fetched)

      ```
       // watch the whole document
       // prefetch offset: 300px
       LazyImg(document, 300);
      ```

**Code:**

```
//
//  LAZY Loading Images 
//
//  Handles lazy loading of images in one or more targeted divs, 
//  or in the entire page. It also keeps track of scrolling and 
//  resizing events, and removes itself if the work is done. 
//
//  Licensed under the terms of the MIT license.
//
//  (c) 2010 Balázs Galambosi
//

(function(){

// glocal variables
var window    = this, 
    instances = {},
    winH;

// cross browser event handling
function addEvent( el, type, fn ) {
  if ( window.addEventListener ) {
    el.addEventListener( type, fn, false );
  } else if ( window.attachEvent ) {
    el.attachEvent( "on" + type, fn );
  } else {
    var old = el["on" + type];
    el["on" + type] = function() { old(); fn(); };
  }
}

// cross browser event handling
function removeEvent( el, type, fn ) {
  if ( window.removeEventListener ) {
    el.removeEventListener( type, fn, false );
  } else if ( window.attachEvent ) {
    el.detachEvent( "on" + type, fn );
  }
}

// cross browser window height
function getWindowHeight() {
  if ( window.innerHeight ) {
    winH = window.innerHeight;
  } else if ( document.documentElement.clientHeight ) {
    winH = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  } else if ( document.body && document.body.clientHeight ) {
    winH = document.body.clientHeight;
  } else {        // fallback:
    winH = 10000; // just load all the images
  }
  return winH;
}

// getBoundingClientRect alternative
function findPos(obj) {
  var top  = 0;
  if (obj && obj.offsetParent) {
    do {
      top += obj.offsetTop || 0;
      top -= obj.scrollTop || 0;
    } while (obj = obj.offsetParent); // 
    return { "top" : top };
  }
}

// top position of an element
var getTopPos = (function() {
  var dummy = document.createElement("div");
  if ( dummy.getBoundingClientRect ) {
    return function( el ) { 
      return el.$$top || el.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    };
  } else {
    return function( el ) { 
      return el.$$top || findPos( el ).top;
    };
  }
})();

// sorts images by their vertical positions
function img_sort( a, b ) {
  return getTopPos( a ) - getTopPos( b );
}

// let's just provide some interface 
// for the outside world
var LazyImg = function( target, offset ) {

  var imgs,    // images array (ordered)
      last,    // last visible image (index)
      id,      // id of the target element
      self;    // this instance

  offset = offset || 200; // for prefetching

  if ( !target ) {
    target = document;
    id = "$document";
  } else if ( typeof target === "string" ) {
    id = target;
    target = document.getElementById( target );
  } else {
    id = target.id || "$undefined";
  }

  // return if this instance already exists
  if ( instances[id] ) {
    return instances[id];
  }

  // or make a new instance
  self = instances[id] = {

    // init & reset
    init: function() {
      imgs = null;
      last = 0;
      addEvent( window, "scroll", self.fetchImages );
      self.fetchImages();
      return this;
    },

    destroy: function() { 
      removeEvent( window, "scroll", self.fetchImages );
      delete instances[id];
    },

    // fetches images, starting at last (index)
    fetchImages: function() {

      var img, temp, len, i;

      // still trying to get the target
      target = target || document.getElementById( id );

      // if it's the first time
      // initialize images array
      if ( !imgs && target ) {

        temp = target.getElementsByTagName( "img" ); 

        if ( temp.length ) {
          imgs = [];
          len  = temp.length;
        } else return;

        // fill the array for sorting
        for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
          img = temp[i];
          if ( img.nodeType === 1 && img.getAttribute("thumb") ) {

              // store them and cache current
              // positions for faster sorting
              img.$$top = getTopPos( img );
              imgs.push( img );
          }
        }
        imgs.sort( img_sort );
      }

      // loop through the images
      while ( imgs[last] ) {

        img = imgs[last];

        // delete cached position
        if ( img.$$top ) img.$$top = null;

        // check if the img is above the fold
        if ( getTopPos( img ) < winH + offset )  {

          // then change the src 
          img.src = img.getAttribute("thumb");
          last++;
        }
        else return;
      }

      // we've fetched the last image -> finished
      if ( last && last === imgs.length )  {
        self.destroy();
      }
    }  
  };
  return self.init();
};

// initialize
getWindowHeight();
addEvent( window, "load",   LazyImg().fetchImages );
addEvent( window, "resize", getWindowHeight       ); 
LazyImg();

window.LazyImg = LazyImg;

}());
```